# Obtaining boundary points of clusters found in DBSCAN algorithm in a counter-clockwise direction

Tags: python, dbscan

I am trying to get the boundary points of each clusters found in DBSCAN algorithm. The points should be in counter clockwise direction.

[image: Problem Scenario of DBSCAN Clusters]

Like, for the clusters, I need the points in chronological order of point labels. 
(e.g.: For cluster 2, I need A->B-->C-->D-->E-->F-->G-->H-->I-->J-->K)

Python implementation of the above mentioned code will be every helpful. If it is not available, could you please help me with efficient algorithm with reference for the above mentioned problem?

Comment: It might help if you can further illustrate your question. Are you looking for a better algorithm? Or having trouble with your implementation?

Comment: I am mainly looking for implementation with an optimal algorithm. @AmarthGûl

Comment: The samples you have indicated in your images are not a convex hull, so I believe your assertion that "convex hull ... does not give me the exact boundary" is instead a miscommunication of the problem you are trying to solve. scipy uses well established and tested algorithms that are extremely rarely found to be wrong. If you could better describe which points you are attempting to select (based on specific criteria) as well as define how you want to interpret the notion of "counter-clockwise" (for non-convex shapes for example), then we may be better able to help.

Comment: What is your rule for deciding that the point 'o' should be included, but not the point slightly south-west of it? And why exclude the two points in the second cluster outside the boundary of the G->H line?

Comment: I want to choose the points in such a way that covers all the points in a polygon of minimal area @Aaron

Comment: I am sorry for not including those points. I have edited the question. Thanks. Actually, I want to choose the points in such a way that covers all the points in a polygon of minimal area

Comment: But the area is lower if you *do* include that point slightly south-west of 'o'. In fact, if you have already chosen which centre you are defining counter-clockwise relative to, and every point needs to be inside the polygon or on its boundary, then the minimal area is achieved by just listing *all* the points counter-clockwise around the centre.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not well defined.

What of the cluster is shaped like a banana, or even a more irregular non-concave set?

As long as your data is Gaussian toy data in 2d - compute the angle to the cluster mean, then sort the values by the angle. In fact, a popular convex hul algorithm (Graham's scan) does exactly this to get the processing order. The trick from Graham may or may not work well enough for you: choose the point with the maximum y coordinate as reference point, and sort points by their angle to this point. It's easy to see that the resulting points may occasionally be out of sequence compared to a more central point, but that this will not matter for the purpose of finding the convex hull.